# How to replace the using of JRParameter.REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER by JasperReportsContext?

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports

The **JRParameter.REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER** is deprecated in version 5.0.
The Javadoc suggests to use *JasperReportsContext* instead.

How to use *JasperReportsContext*?

The use is requested when using the Struts2 jasper plugin.

```
connection=dataSource.getConnection();
reportParams.put(JRParameter.REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER, new SimpleFileResolver(reportsDir));
```

Comment: Look at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/plugins/jasperreports/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/views/jasperreports/JasperReportsResult.java#L314-L320). You can open an issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem ([File resolver in Jasper Reports 5.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004325/file-resolver-in-jasper-reports-5-0-1/15023748#15023748)) and after many hours I found the answer in the JasperReports sources.

```
LocalJasperReportsContext ctx = new LocalJasperReportsContext(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance());
ctx.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
ctx.setFileResolver(new FileResolver() {
        @Override
        public File resolveFile(String s) {
            return new File(s);
        }
    });
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperfile);

JasperFillManager fillmgr = JasperFillManager.getInstance(ctx);
JasperExportManager exmgr = JasperExportManager.getInstance(ctx);
```

**Edit:**
The proper solution would include reporting the problem to the plugin's project ticketing system and maybe propose a patch for the resolver implementation.

While waiting for the patch to get accepted, you can extend the `JasperReportsResult` class and just override the `doExecute()` method, using the code above, with something like this:

```
protected void doExecute(String finalLocation, ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        // Will throw a runtime exception if no "datasource" property. TODO Best place for that is...?
        initializeProperties(invocation);

        LOG.debug("Creating JasperReport for dataSource = {}, format = {}", dataSource, format);

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) invocation.getInvocationContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) invocation.getInvocationContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_RESPONSE);

        // Handle IE special case: it sends a "contype" request first.
        // TODO Set content type to config settings?
        if ("contype".equals(request.getHeader("User-Agent"))) {
            try (OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()) {
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setContentLength(0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error("Error writing report output", e);
                throw new ServletException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return;
        }

        // Construct the data source for the report.
        ValueStack stack = invocation.getStack();
        ValueStackDataSource stackDataSource = null;

        Connection conn = (Connection) stack.findValue(connection);
        if (conn == null)
            stackDataSource = new ValueStackDataSource(stack, dataSource, wrapField);

        if ("https".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getScheme())) {
            // set the the HTTP Header to work around IE SSL weirdness
            response.setHeader("CACHE-CONTROL", "PRIVATE");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "maxage=3600");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "none");
        }

        // Determine the directory that the report file is in and set the reportDirectory parameter
        // For WW 2.1.7:
        //  ServletContext servletContext = ((ServletConfig) invocation.getInvocationContext().get(ServletActionContext.SERVLET_CONFIG)).getServletContext();
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) invocation.getInvocationContext().get(ServletActionContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
        String systemId = servletContext.getRealPath(finalLocation);
        Map parameters = new ValueStackShadowMap(stack);
        File directory = new File(systemId.substring(0, systemId.lastIndexOf(File.separator)));
        parameters.put("reportDirectory", directory);
        parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, invocation.getInvocationContext().getLocale());

        // put timezone in jasper report parameter
        if (timeZone != null) {
            timeZone = conditionalParse(timeZone, invocation);
            final TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
            if (tz != null) {
                // put the report time zone
                parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_TIME_ZONE, tz);
            }
        }

        // Add any report parameters from action to param map.
        Map reportParams = (Map) stack.findValue(reportParameters);
        if (reportParams != null) {
            LOG.debug("Found report parameters; adding to parameters...");
            parameters.putAll(reportParams);
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream output;
        JasperPrint jasperPrint;

        LocalJasperReportsContext ctx = new LocalJasperReportsContext(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance());
        ctx.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
        ctx.setFileResolver(parameters.get());
        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperfile);

        JasperFillManager fillmgr = JasperFillManager.getInstance(ctx);
        JasperExportManager exmgr = JasperExportManager.getInstance(ctx);

        // Fill the report and produce a print object
        try {
            JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(new File(systemId));
            if (conn == null) {
                jasperPrint = fillmgr.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, stackDataSource);
            }
            else {
                jasperPrint = fillmgr.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);
            }
        } catch (JRException e) {
            LOG.error("Error building report for uri {}", systemId, e);
            throw new ServletException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        // Export the print object to the desired output format
        try {
            if (contentDisposition != null || documentName != null) {
                final StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
                tmp.append((contentDisposition == null) ? "inline" : contentDisposition);

                if (documentName != null) {
                    tmp.append("; filename=");
                    tmp.append(documentName);
                    tmp.append(".");
                    tmp.append(format.toLowerCase());
                }

                response.setHeader("Content-disposition", tmp.toString());
            }

            JRExporter exporter;

            if (format.equals(FORMAT_PDF)) {
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                exporter = new JRPdfExporter(ctx);
            } else if (format.equals(FORMAT_CSV)) {
                response.setContentType("text/csv");
                exporter = new JRCsvExporter(ctx);
            } else if (format.equals(FORMAT_HTML)) {
                response.setContentType("text/html");

                // IMAGES_MAPS seems to be only supported as "backward compatible" from JasperReports 1.1.0

                Map imagesMap = new HashMap();
                request.getSession(true).setAttribute("IMAGES_MAP", imagesMap);

                exporter = new JRHtmlExporter(ctx);
                exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_MAP, imagesMap);
                exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, request.getContextPath() + imageServletUrl);

                // Needed to support chart images:
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.jasper_print", jasperPrint);
            } else if (format.equals(FORMAT_XLS)) {
                response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                exporter = new JRXlsExporter(ctx);
            } else if (format.equals(FORMAT_XML)) {
                response.setContentType("text/xml");
                exporter = new JRXmlExporter(ctx);
            } else if (format.equals(FORMAT_RTF)) {
                response.setContentType("application/rtf");
                exporter = new JRRtfExporter(ctx);
            } else {
                throw new ServletException("Unknown report format: " + format);
            }

            Map exportParams = (Map) stack.findValue(exportParameters);
            if (exportParams != null) {
                LOG.debug("Found export parameters; adding to exporter parameters...");
                exporter.getParameters().putAll(exportParams);
            }

            output = exportReportToBytes(jasperPrint, exporter);
        } catch (JRException e) {
            LOG.error("Error producing {} report for uri {}", format, systemId, e);
            throw new ServletException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.warn("Could not close db connection properly", e);
            }
        }

        response.setContentLength(output.size());
        // Will throw ServletException on IOException.
        writeReport(response, output);
    }
```

and than use the new extension as the **Result** in Struts. Please test if the method is implemented correctly.

The final solution should include the use of a context instance setter on the Result object, or maybe a global static context instance accessible from the Result object.

Comment: My question (so long) was not so good. I use jasper struts2 plugin where you need to pass parameters (struts manages by itself the fill and export operations). I passed a hashmap parameter to struts. In this hashmap I put my parameters and the fileResolver :
    reportParams.put(JRParameter.REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER, new SimpleFileResolver(reportsDir)); That's what I wan't to replace.

Comment: @Rydermark But the answer is right for the question, isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no or I don't see how. Maybe can you precise something more.

Comment: @Rydermark Is it more obvious now? You have to pass the file resolver to the context instead of filling it to the `reportParams`.

Comment: Still not. The issue is very specific to Struts2 jasper  plugin where you haven't to build a context. I get no issue to produce the ByteArrayOutputStream "in a normal way". The context is not accessible when working with the plugin. You just have the parameters map, the connection, the location of the report. Many thanks for your efforts.